# Не сохраняется информация о просмотрах страниц на сайте

Tags: php, curl

Нужно сделать скрипт ходить по профилям пользователей на сайте.

Авторизацию и парсинг ID пользователей реализовал все работает.

На сайте можно просматривать гостей твоего профиля, как реализовано в Мой мир mail.ru.

Создал второго пользователя и перехожу на его страницу(профиль) просмотр не засчитывается, захожу в профиль и не вижу своего просмотра, cookie в файл сохраняются не могу понять что я делаю не так...

```
$html_like = $this->get_page_https3('http://ru.www.сайт.com/member/13243345',''); // Переходим на профиль 

private function get_page_https3($url, $postdata) 
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('cookiefile.txt'));  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('cookiefile.txt')); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $post = $postdata;

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl); 

    return $html; 

}
```

Comment: Не знаю php, поэтому спрошу на всякий случай. Здесь точно представлен весь код, который сохраняет **и** читает информацию о просмотрах? Проблема может быть на любом из этапов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это фрагмент кода, полный код слишком огромен :), все остальное работает правильно.

Comment: не, весь код сайта ни в коем случае не нужно публиковать. ) Но в вопросе должно быть достаточно кода для воспроизведения проблемы. Поэтому на всякий случай уточняю.

Comment: Сначала не понял , что вы делаете , думал вы свой сайт так тестите . Скорее всего голый curl вам в этом не поможет , так как он просто загрузит выдачу сервера . По хорошему нужен эмулятор , хорошая штука silenium .

Answer (score 1):

Возможно просмотр засчитывается не просто за посещение страницы. Может просмотр засчитывается если ты провел какое-то время на странице пользователя. Может быть много вариантов.

Comment: Точно не за время, секунды хватит чтоб просмотр засчитался, проверял.

Comment: Привет, добро пожаловать на SO на русском. Если вы только предполагаете направление решения, то для этого лучше использовать комментарий. Ответы всё-таки для более полных решений задачи. Тут есть небольшая нестыковка – комментарии к чужим вопросам вы сможете оставлять, только получив 50+ репутации. Но она быстро зарабатывается.

Comment: Если не возражаете, я могу преобразовать этот ответ в комментарий.

Comment: Если вы накручиваете просмотры через js (после загрузки страницы ajax например) то работать не будет .

Comment: js не использую

Comment: А какое должно выполнится условие что бы просмотр засчитался ?

Comment: Если бы я точно знал, то вопрос бы не задавал здесь, а сделал сам. Вот сайт meetme.com если это как то сможет помочь.

Comment: Открой страницу профиля в браузере и посмотри исходный код. Есть вероятность, что просмотр засчитывается через js используя ajax. Выложи исходный код этой страницы куда нибудь, посмотрим вместе.

Comment: @thecoder Сохранил в файл исходный код, ссылка https://yadi.sk/d/Pcl1ILZlmcVNJ

Comment: @paketik, посмотрел файл.
В начале файла идет большой кусок кода на JS. Насколько я понял используется библиотека prototype.js. Что именно делает этот код сказать не могу, т.к. не знаком с ней. И если не ошибаюсь, то в этом коде есть использование ajax, т.е. просмотр может засчитываться в этом куске кода. Другие куски кода JS не отвечают за засчитывает просмотра.
В коде есть ссылки 
    /?mysession=cmVnaXN0cmF0aW9uX215cGljdHVyZXM=
Возможно эта переменная играет роль в подсчете просмотров. А при заходе сессия не создается или не принимается сайтом.

Comment: Как вариант по пробуй добавить
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
для получения всех заголовков.

Comment: @paketik, а вы не перепутали данные? Т.е. в $url должна быть страница одного юзера, а куки авторизации другого юзера. Может сейчас вы пытаетесь просмотреть свою же страницу. И что в результате хранится в $html.

Comment: @thecoder Что то не получается на Curl, где то не прохожу проверку и не засчитывают просмотр, попробовал лайк ставить на фото тоже не удается отправляю get запрос с параметрами возвращается ошибка "Sorry, but your request could not be completed at this time.", подумываю сделать на с# с применением Webbrowser, хотя там еще больше гем*роя.

Comment: На perl проще, надо юзать mechanize